# Email receive delay on apps script when using Checkbox

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, google-forms

When the checkbox is checked, then email will be sent to recipient, but the email is being delayed. I am not sure if email won't sent at all or being delayed.

```
 function sendEmailforcollect() {
  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(). getSheetByName("FR2");  //declare ss as variable spreadsheet, SpreadsheetApp is declaring the app's name and getSheetByName is Sheet's name
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CEmailTemp").getRange(1,1).getValue();
  

  //Logger.log(messageBody);



  for(var i = 2;i<=lr;i++) {  
                       
    var currentEmails = ss.getRange(i,4).getValue();
    var currentBuyerName = ss.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var currentAssetName = ss.getRange(i,6).getValue();   //declare from table 
    var currentStatusOfEmail = ss.getRange(i,11).getValue();


     var subjectLine = "We have received your proof of payment"   //Declare Email's subject
     var messageBody = templateText.replace("{Buyer Name}",currentBuyerName).replace("{Asset Name}",currentAssetName).replace("{Email}",currentEmails); 

try{
  if(currentStatusOfEmail == 1){
    MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmails,subjectLine,messageBody); //avoid email sent multiple times 
    ss.getRange(i,12).setValue("EMAIL SENT"); 
  
  }
}
catch {continue;}

}}
```

[column K (checkbox) Column L (show email status)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUE6r.png)
Only row 2 shows email sent but not final row even when checkbox if tick.

The emails are in Column D.

Please help me. There are other formula and codes on other sheet too , is it overwriting each other? I've tried different method to use checkbox but still fail. Please assist.

Comment: Multiple points to improve/correct, but here is aone of the possible directions. When you tick the checkbox, you should get only the active row number and process that. No need to do a for loop. For that case, I'd get it using `getActiveRange()` and `getRow()`...then `getValue()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using an installable onEdit function:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "FR2" && e.range.columnStart == 11 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    const r = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    let templateText = e.source.getSheetByName("CEmailTemp").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
    let subjectLine = "We have received your proof of payment"
    let messageBody = templateText.replace("{Buyer Name}", r[1]).replace("{Asset Name}", r[5]).replace("{Email}", r[3]);
    if (r[10] == 1) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(r[3], subjectLine, messageBody);
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 12).setValue("EMAIL SENT");
    }
  }
}
```